# Is this transmute from array of SIMD to regular numeric types undefined behaviour?

Tags: arrays, rust, simd, reinterpret-cast

I have an array of floating point values and I need to do some easily vectorizable operations like taking the sum of all of them and then dividing them all by that sum. I also need to access (mostly read) individual elements of the array. I figured I could use a SIMD type to enable the vectorization of the array. Whenever I'd need to do a lot of things with individual elements of the array, I would transmute the array into a reference to an array of regular floating point values, and access that reference instead, like so:

```
extern crate simd;

use simd::x86::avx::f32x8;

fn main() {
    let values8: [f32x8; 100] = [f32x8::splat(1.1); 100];
    let values: &[f32; 800] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&values8) };

    println!("{}", values[333]);
}
```

This compiles and seems to work just fine. But I'm worried that this is undefined behaviour because [I read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/transmutes.html) that:

> Transmuting between non-repr(C) types is UB

I think SIMD types (like `simd::x86::avx::f32x8`) are `repr(simd)` and I don't think `[f32; 800]` is `repr(C)` either.

I know I can use the `extract` method on SIMD types to get those individual floating point values, but using the aforementioned transmute-to-a-regular-array scheme would make the code much simpler.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there's a good reason why `f32x8` doesn't implement `Borrow<[f32]>` like Vec does, which would be a half-way house.  Maybe the layout/ordering isn't guaranteed to be compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The early definition in [this Pre-RFC](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-simd-groundwork/2343) states that

> It is illegal to take an internal reference to the fields of a repr(simd) type, because the representation of booleans may require to change, so that booleans are bit-packed. The official external library providing SIMD support will have private fields so this will not be generally observable.

This would obviously forbid turning a simd type into an array.

The actual RFC [changed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1199#issuecomment-131182417) that, so apparently you are allowed to reference the inner things. The RFC also states that the layout and alignments are platform dependent.

Since all platforms that I know of don't add padding to trivial simd types like `f32x8`, you can assume that the layout of a `f32x8` is "the same" as a `[f32; 8]` in terms of that it contains 8 `f32`s tightly packed in a 32 byte piece of memory. The order may be arbitrary though.

---

> "Transmuting between non-repr(C) types is UB" I think simd types (like simd::x86::avx::f32x8) are repr(simd) and I don't think [f32; 800] is repr(C) either.

Technically you are neither transmuting a `repr(simd)` type nor a `[f32; 800]`, you are transmuting a reference to another reference, but the result is the same.

---

As noted by @Chris Emerson, the unsafety in your example comes from the breaking of the lifetime chain. To reinstate that, create an abstraction boundary:

```
fn simd_slice(simd: &[f32x8; 100]) -> &[f32; 800] {
    unsafe { &*(simd as *const [f32x8; 100] as *const [f32; 800]) }
}
```

Comment: *"The order may be arbitrary though."* Does this mean that (given my example) `values8[0].extract(5)` doesn't necessarily return the same value as `values[5]` ?

Comment: yes, that's what that statement means. The order is platform defined, so you probably need to read what llvm does with simd or what your architecture does with simd.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific guarantees (which I can't find), I don't think you can conclude that it's safe.

In fact as written above it's definitely unsafe for a slightly different reason; you've laundered a reference to `values8` which isn't tracked by the borrow checker; it let me do this:

```
extern crate simd;

use simd::f32x4;

fn main() {
    let mut values8: [f32x4; 100] = [f32x4::splat(1.1); 100];
    let values: &[f32; 400] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(&values8) };

    let t = &mut values8[4];
    println!("{}", values[333]); // but there's a mutable reference!
}
```

Comment: But I'm mostly interested in whether it is already undefined behaviour to do the transmute or is it fine to do the transmute assuming that later on you use the resulting reference variable in a memory-safe manner.

Comment: just using it in a memory safe manner does not make it memory safe, you need an abstraction boundary. So if you dump all the unsafety into a function, then you can't ever use it wrongly outside that function if you setup the lifetimes correctly.